# Is this true for quotients of finitely generated abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

> Let $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{k_1}}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_2}^{k_2}}\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{k_n}}$, where the $p_i$'s are primes.
>
> Let $H\cong \mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{l_1}}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_2}^{l_2}}\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{l_n}}\leq G$.
>
> Is it true that $G/H\cong\mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{k_1-l_1}}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_2}^{k_2-l_2}}\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{k_n-l_n}}$?

(Primes with power $0$ are omitted from the direct sum)

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_6 /\mathbb{Z}_3\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$, hence hoping that it can generalise to the above.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you assuming that the $p_i$s are distinct?

Comment: Not really, they can be repeated

Comment: Then, why do you expect what yo need? For example, if $G=\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}p\mathbb{Z}$, the quotient could be two different things.